# Как реализовать сортировку многомерного массива в python

Tags: python, сортировка

Задача.
Используя объектно-ориентированный язык программирования Python, при помощи
классов можно решать различные задачи.
Необходимо:

1. Создать класс “Student” который содержит следующие параметры (full_name - имя
   студента, group_number - номер группы и progress - список полученных оценок);
2. Осуществить список, который сортируется по имени, затем выводятся студенты,
   имеющие неудовлетворительные оценки.

Это задача, которую мне надо было сделать. В теории у меня получается огромный массив из учеников, в котором у каждого ученика есть имя[0], группа[1] и еще один массив оценок. Так вот, как мне отсортировать студентов по алфавиту не теряя номер группы и оценок?

```
class Students:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Students = set()
    def add_student(self, student_parameters: tuple | list) -> None:
        self.Students.add(student_parameters)
    def sorting(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Ладно, сортировать вы не умеете. Но где хоть вами созданный класс с указанными атрибутами?  На этом сайте за вас задачи не решают. На этом сайте помогают тем, кто пытается что-то решить сам, но у него что-то конкретное не выходит. Совет. Откройте книгу по Python. Прочитайте про списки, словари, сортировку. Попробуйте сам написать хоть что-то. И вот когда у вас не получиться - приходите сюда с конкретным вопросом.